# Citrix Performance monitoring

Tags: monitoring, citrix

I has a strange thing which appears on my Citrix Farm today. 
My users are equiped with a Thin client Axel Model 80F, and today, one of them sustained a problem on it.

He opened a citrix's Publish Desktop session (Host by a farm of Windows 2003 R2 SP2 Servers), he loaded Lotus Notes and a mail who contained an PDF attached file.

Once he has opened his PDF File, his session has freezed.
We've just reboot the Thin Client, and log in again on the session (which hasn't been closed during the process).

Once we have log in again, we try to read the pdf and once again afer half a page the session freeze again (I can see the mouse moving on the screen but can make anything).

Then I close the session, reboot correctly the thin client, and "Tada" with the same manipulationsn averything is correct and we don't facing any freeze.

Well Now my question is:

Is that bug came from the thin client or the server about you?
I've checked on my farm and I don't have any alert from the Citrix's Monitoring console logs.

According to me it's due to the Thin Client BUT I ddon't have enought monitoring tools to be sure of that.
So do you have some quite godd monitoring tools or method?

My config:

Windows 2003 R2 SP2
Citrix Xenapp 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what your Citrix Licenses are then you might have access to [Citrix Edgesight](http://www.citrix.com/edgesight) which is really good for identifying these types of finger pointing performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

OK many thanks for your answer.
I'll check this software.

My problems seems solved since I've reboot the Thin client.